# Django signals doesn't update related model when foreign key updated

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I want to update a related model every time a foreign key is changed using signals, similar to `m2m_changed` but for a foreign key.

***User model:***

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    balance = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

***Transaction model:***

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='transactions')
    order = models.OneToOneField('Payment.Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='transaction')
    transaction_type = models.CharField(choices=[
        ('transfer', 'Transfer'),
        ('received', 'Received'),
    ], max_length=20, default='transfer')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I need that when a new transaction is created under the User, it's collected to the balance.

***Signal code:***

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
    def collect_transaction(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    balance = instance.transactions.aggregate(Sum('order__price'))
    print(balance)
```

but it works only when I update it from the User model, and not Transaction.

**For example, this code will make the signals work:**

```
user.transactions.add(transaction)
user.save()
```

**Whereas this code won't make the signals work:**

```
Transaction.objects.create(user=1, order=1, transaction_type='received')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your signal will only be sent when the `User` model is saved. It seems you want it to be sent when any `Transaction` is saved, so you should try using `Transaction` as the sender instead of User:

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Transaction)
def collect_transactions(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = instance.user
    user.balance = user.transactions.aggregate(Sum('order__price'))
    user.save()
```

As for your original example of having a signal when User is saved, I'm trying to think of a case where you'd be updating User but not updating its related transactions and yet need the balance to be updated. If there does exist such a case, you might just be better off overriding the `save()` method on the User model.